# Javascript - removing object from array by key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects

```
let people = [{

  Name: 'Bob',

  Age: '45',
},
{
  Name: 'Jim',

  Age: '45',
}

];

let person = people.filter(person => person.Name=== 'Bob')
```

This returns Bob but how do I delete him?

This only seems to delete a property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

so it seems I need an index or maybe there is a better ES6 way?

Comment: you wanna remove an element from array ? `splice()` ??

Comment: just flip it around - `let person = people.filter(person => person.Name!== 'Bob')`. Filter will only return elements that return false to your condition and ignore the others.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `splice` and `findIndex` methods and remove specific object from an array.

```js
let people = [{"Name":"Bob","Age":"45"},{"Name":"Jim","Age":"45"}]

people.splice(people.findIndex(({Name}) => Name == "Bob"), 1);
console.log(people)
```

Comment: This works also as above answer did not work for me `people.splice(people.findIndex((foo) => foo.Name == "Bob"), 1);
console.log(people)`

Answer (score 4):

To remove bob simply do the opposite equality check

```
let person = people.filter(person => person.Name !== 'Bob')
```

To mutate the original array, you can use splice

```
const index = people.findIndex(person => person.Name === 'Bob');
if (index > -1) {
   people.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I mean from the original object, not remove I suppose I mean delete.

Comment: `people = people.filter(person => person.Name !== 'Bob') ;`

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the index of the object where `name = "Bob"`
2. Remove it from the array using `splice()`

> people.splice(people.findIndex(({Name}) => Name == "Bob"), 1);

Answer (score 0):

Just simply change your code in the filter section from "===" to "!==" to delete it.

```js
  let people = [
    {
      Name: "Bob",

      Age: "45",
    },
    {
      Name: "Jim",

      Age: "45",
    },
  ];

  let person = people.filter((person) => person.Name !== "Bob");
  console.log(person);
```